# Perform an action in Spring when database value is changed by another backend service

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 2 projects. The first project is using spring boot hibernate and angular.js. The other is a backend service, which receives data and inserts it into a table.

I want to perform an action in the spring hibernate project when the backend service inserts some data.

The backend service is a Java program.

Comment: There are not enough details in the question, what approach have you tried?

Comment: That's not easy at all. You have to either continuously poll the database or use a (very fragile) DB trigger that notifies you somehow.

Comment: Hibernate interceptors can be used for trigger purpose, but i have different scenario here. Database operations are performed by back end java service and not spring project. I need a way to talk from one project to another project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of an Message Queue. After your backend finishes inserting the records, you can push a message to this MQ and then your subscribed spring boot app can receive this message and do whatever you want.

On the other hand, you can expose a service in your spring boot app and your backend can call it after finishing the insert.

Comment: Good suggestions, Duy. Communicating via the database (which implies polling) is the other option.